# Override Less file

Tags: overrides, css, less

im work on a new magento 2 page. Now i want change a css class over my custom theme.less file. But how can i override the css class?

I want override the padding from the .header.content class which is located in the layout.less

```
.navigation,
.breadcrumbs,
.page-header .header.panel,
.header.content,
.footer.content,
.page-wrapper > .widget,
.page-wrapper > .page-bottom,
.block.category.event,
.top-container,
.page-main {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: @layout__max-width;
    padding-left: @layout-indent__width;
    padding-right: @layout-indent__width;
    width: auto;
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your theme and create a file at `app/design/frontend/{Your_Vendor_Namespace}/{Your_Theme}/web/css/source/_extend.less`. Inside this file place what ever code you would like to override, i.e.:

```
.header.content {
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
```

After you have made this change, there are a few different ways to compile the file to show on your front end, [This guide goes into more detail](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html). I would recommend setting up grunt to do your compilation, it's by far the fastest and most dependable.

**Why this works**

Magento will scan through the specific folders in the install for `.less` files, and when it finds them, it will compile them into the two `.css` files that get loaded into the head of your site `styles-m.css` and `styles-l.css`. As long as your file is named correctly, it will get pulled in, and since your file is in your theme, it will be loaded last and comiled at the bottom of the sheet, so your style will have [css specifisity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) in the cascade.

A quick note about the `_theme.less` file. Only one of those files gets pulling into compilation, with your theme's file having the priority. This means that if you are inheriting from the Luma theme, that Luma theme's `_theme.less` file will not be loaded if you have one in your theme. This can cause unexpected results, so if you are using this file to change a few things, copy the content of the inherited theme's `_theme.less` into your file and then make your edits at the bottom.